# After adding a path to a group in fabricjs, toSVG() gives an svg image that is different from the canvas layout

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I have a group of shapes that are supposed to be moved and scaled together on the canvas. For doing this I added all of these to a fabric Group. One of the shape is a fabric Path. While it adds properly on the canvas, when converting the Canvas to SVG, it changes it's position.

I have made a fiddle for it : http://jsfiddle.net/RZcY7/4/
Export svg button will push the svg data to console. click there to open it in browser. It can be seen that the position of triangle(which is a fabric Path) is different on canvas and svg.

Here's the code:

```
var DefaultGroupSettings = {
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    hasBorders: true,
    hasControls: true,
    hasRotatingPoint: true,
    lockUniScaling: true
};

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById('c'));

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    angle: 30,
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
});
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 50,
    left: 175,
    top: 75,
    fill: '#aac'
});

var group = new fabric.Group([rect, circle], DefaultGroupSettings);
canvas.add(group);

var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 200 100 L 170 200 z');

path.set({
    top: 150,
    left: 100
});
group.addWithUpdate(path);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Is it an issue to add a Path to a Group? If yes, how can I club Path and an Object together?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: everything is ok there, triangle Path is at the same position as you have drawn. Check again please.

Comment: @rafi there's a difference between the canvas and the image. In the canvas, triangle's vertex just touches the square, but in the svg, it lies inside the square.

Comment: oh sorry, my mistake....

Comment: It is correct now. Fabricjs changed quite a bit last year and may svg and canvas rendering happened. Now the output is the same.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/asturur/RZcY7/14/ see updated fiddle.